# How to set menu and header in one div magento2?

Tags: magento2, theme, menu, navigation, layout-update

In my custom theme I need to put the header and menu in one div. Now I have the following structure:
[image]

How can I add blocks in one div so I can have this structure ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following to your theme's `default.xml` layout file:

```
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header.container" />
```